# Right database model for M:N relationship with different schemas

Tags: sql, postgresql, database-design, microservices

I need help with choose right database design. We have multiple database schemas:

- picture schema
- foo schema
- bar schema
- ...

`picture schema` contains tables about uploaded pictures, where root table `picture` has id with uuid type.

`foo` and `bar` schemas contains main tables `foo` and `bar` which have id with type uuid as well. Each record of these tables has cardinality with picture `M:N`.

There cannot be foreign key because of different schemas. So what is right design of join tables? Should each of schemas (`foo` and `bar`) contains joining table with picture_id like this:

in foo schema:

```
| foo_id (uuid) | picture_id (uuid) |
```

and in bar schema:

```
| bar_id (uuid) | picture_id (uuid) |
```

or should I create only one joining table in picture schema thanks to uuid type like this:

```
|picture_id (uuid) | entity_id (uuid) |
```

entity_id will be id of foo or bar - it doesn't matter because uuid is always unique right? What do you think? You can consider each of schema is used in different microservice. Thank you in advice.

Answer (score 0):

It is absolutely no problem to have foreign keys between tables in different schemas. Just qualify the table names with the schema:

```
ALTER TABLE foo.foo
   ADD FOREIGN KEY (x) REFERENCES bar.bar(y);
```

You can place a junction table in either schema; I personally believe that it doesn't matter much where. If you are picky about that, you could create an extra schema `crossref` that contains such junction tables.

Comment: Thanks, but I still need solve where put joining table

Comment: Oh, I see. I have added my opinion on that to the answer.